# Empty list in visual studio references

Tags: visual-studio, reference

I am trying to add a reference and there is no signal reference in the list.  It's empty. Also I cannot click browse to add a reference.

Any help? So the list is empty without any references:

[image: Screenshot here]

Thanks

Comment: Also I am new in all this so sorry if I am doing something dumb.

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

File / New / Project select Win32 Console Application and under Solution select Add Solution:
([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xJrg.pngbox,)) and click ok. Then click next, clear the **Precompiled header** checkbox and Finish. Once this project is added to your solution, you will be able to right-click References (under your original project) and see the last project you added available under Projects > Solution.

link:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx